# is there a way to check if a file exists with the glob * in Unix Shell Scripting?

Tags: unix, csh

Suppose I have the file "FILE_${RUNDATE}_0957_PROD.csv" to check if it doesn't exist, it must bypass the IF statement.  If I setenv the variable $FILENAME with the full name it works with the code below, but using the '*' reg-ex ("0957" represents a timestamp which I don't know the exact value) it enters into the IF statement.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set RUNDATE = `date +'%Y%m%d'`

setenv FILENAME "DATA_${RUNDATE}_*_PROD.csv"

if ( ! -eq "$FILENAME" ) then
    /bin/echo "File NOT Found Locally! \n"
endif
```

Comment: `*` is not a regex.  It is a glob.  They are very different.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like you solved your problem?